# Android unicode char error for contacts

Tags: android, galaxy

I exported contacts, including Arabic contacts, to another phone. Then I added a new partition to the phone's "Partition SDcard". Afterwards I retrieved the contacts from the other phone but Arabic contacts appear as rubbish.

The phone I used is a galaxy y dous

Answer (score -1):

I believe the official support for Arabic characters was started to appear in **Honeycomb**.

And galaxy y is up till **Gingerbread**.

Comment: your answer did not give me any hint to solve the problem, although I will remove vote down

Comment: if you read carefully, it was a hint that you cannot get it done. What else do you want me to write? a piece of code printing that it may not be possible?  :)